# openfire rest api get request is empty

Tags: php, rest, xmpp, openfire

I have the XMPP-server openfire. 
Also i have added the "rest api plugin" and tested it with the Chrome Tool "Postman", and it works fine.

Request:

```
http://myhost.net:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users
```

Header:

```
Authorization:myPasswort
```

Result:

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "username": "admin",
      "name": "Administrator",
      "email": "info@admin.de",
      "properties": null
    },
  ...
```

Now i want to use the result in a my composer app from appgyver.com. Same input, but always the server result:

Response code: 500. {"error":"Internal server error."}

Then i try a get request with a php script:

```
$url = "myhost.net/plugins/restapi/v1/users";

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'Authorization' => 'myPasswort'
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
var_dump($http_response_header);
echo "\r\n";
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);
```

with the result: NULL bool(false)

What i doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with follow php snippet:

```
    <?php 
      $url = "http://localhost:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users";
      $curl = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept application/json", "Authorization: PehtV8mbAm5M5MM0"));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
      $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
      $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      echo $json_response;
      curl_close($curl);
   ?>
```

Just change to your URL and the authorization key.